# Make onClick function that sends you to a link without opening a new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, onclick, material-ui

I am using Material UI and have imported a home icon into my navbar like that

```
<Home edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="home" 
onClick={event =>  window.location.href='/
<Home fontSize="large"</Home>
```

Is there some specific code instead for `window.location.href` to make it scroll to the section without opening the window again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using react-router-dom your best option.

I have created a code sandbox to show you the proper use of react-router-doms useHistory hook.  Please reference App.js in order to see how to properly define routes.  Please reference the Home page in order to reference proper use of the useHistory() hook provided by react-router-dom

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-forked-u58hr?file=/Home.js

Comment: What do I have to write in my App.js ? I have only this ```function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">   
      <PageOne/>
      <PageTwo/>
    </div>
  );
} ```

Comment: The code sandbox I linked shows you how to set up your routes.

Comment: Each page can be defined as a route in your application.  You can then utilize react-router-dom to navigate between them

Comment: Please note react-router-dom is a package you must install as a dependency in your project